Question about Schengen visa
I'm a PhD student in the UK, with a history of not finding any visa appointments to go to an international conference. I have an upcoming summer school in Germany, and although I could not find a single appointment for a German visa, I managed to get an appointment for a Lithuania visa (tourism) for the day after tomorrow. I have a few questions:

How long do I need to stay in Lithuania? Does it have to be greater than my stay in Germany (which is 7 days)?

Does Lithuania have to be my first point of entry? Does it have to be my point of departure? In my visa appointment I need to show return tickets to the UK. So could it be of the following forms?


UK-> Lithuania -> Germany -> UK
or
UK -> Germany -> Lithuania -> UK

Does this answer your question? At which embassy should I apply for a Schengen visa when staying a few days in several countries?

Lithuania should be the most important focus of your trip (no need to arrive or depart from there). But the "I had no intention of visiting Lithuania" is not a good start. I would avoid such things, A visa refusal is much worst (and could affect also future visa for UK). Try hard to find an appointment. Try to do some short holidays in Schengen area (with more flexible periods) to gain some more general entry visa (so not a short term plan)

@GiacomoCatenazzi I understand what you are saying. What if I planned a week-long trip to Lithuania for the month of May/June, and apply for a double entry Schengen visa, with the intention of flying to Germany in July?

@NotEuler If you can get a multi-entry visa and have the money to travel to Europe twice, that's also an option. Lithuania is very beautiful (all three Baltic countries are) and your second trip can be anywhere else in the Schengen Area.

@Johnnyjanko I've heard that the multiple entry has some prerequisites to getting it so I'm thinking double entry. If I intend to stay in Germany for a week, how long does my Lithuania stay have to be minimum? Also, if I plan Lithuania in May/June and Germany in July, does that work in terms of visa validity?

Note that this is not the intended purpose of dual entry visa and there is no guarantee and no reason for any country to give you one. They can always decide to issue a single entry visa, even if you asked for something else, and my interpretation is that it is what they should do as far as the Schengen regulations are concerned.

Is there another German consulate in the UK where you could apply?

@GiacomoCatenazzi Note that if you apply for a Schengen visa at the wrong consulate, your visa is not refused, but the consulate will not process your application at all and even refund the visa fee and tell you where to adress your application.  This will have no negative impact on the applicant's future, but for sure vaste some time.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo: right, but so if they ask "your intention" you should answer "I have no interest in staying in Lithuania", and probably you get send away. Which it is not useful.  My concern are more if one lie the pourpose: the outcome depends on person and staff. I had to put the lie in my comment.

You're not really asking the right questions. The reason your travel is taking place is the summer school so Germany is your main destination. Legally speaking, this is unambiguous.
Consequently you are simply not supposed to apply to for a visa from Lithuania and Lithuania should decline to process the visa and refer you to the German consulate instead. There is no point devising some other scheme as you are doing in the comments, the answer will always remain the same.
In practice, the main problem you will face is how to present your trip: If you do not disclose the summer school in Germany, do not provide an invitation letter, etc. you are engaging in deception and it could backfire badly (visa refusal). If you are upfront about it, Lithuania is likely to decline to process your application (not bad but you would be back to square one, without a visa).
Length of stay, etc. only come into play if you try to hide the nature of your trip and try to pretend this is a purely touristic trip, which it is not.

This only means OP has to convince himself first that Lithuania is his main destination, right?

@Jan That's one way to look at it. Alternatively, if you book tickets to Lithuania, a two-week hotel stay, and don't talk about Germany at all, you may get away with the fraud. I just don't see anything in-between.

@Relaxed I see the term "fraud" being thrown around a lot in this context. I'm assuming they come from privileged members of the western world who have never faced the struggle of visa refusal. Us less fortunate people of a third world country face discrimination despite outstanding academic record, for something that is simply out of our control.

The rules as to where you should apply for your Schengen visa exist for two reasons: To spread the workload in a fair way over the different countries, and to avoid visa shopping. The OP wants to do exactly that: visa shopping. And while I can understand why, (and I understand the frustration off those that have to jump to all kinds of hoops to visit Europe) it is still against the rules, and can indeed backfire badly.

@NotEuler While I recognise your frustration, the rules that determine which country should process an application apply to everyone. There is no discrimination inherent in that rule. If you have a history of not finding any visa appointments to go to an international conference perhaps you should have planned further in advance for a summer school trip, given there’s a 6 month window to apply and by their nature such events take place during peak holiday season.

@NotEuler That's true, I am actually very aware of that and often annoyed at the tone of some of the answers on this site. I do not mean to judge and I apologize if the way I phrased my answer suggested otherwise. I am simply using the word “fraud” in its technical legal sense (e.g. article 34 of the Schengen visa code). You need to realize this is what it is, the risk it carries and act accordingly.

@Traveller "You should have applied in advance" - that would require me to have clairvoyance. The summer schools are often not announced months ahead, and even if they are, it still takes time for them to consider my application and send me an invitation letter. I apply for visas as soon as I receive confirmation from the schools. I have been accepted to the best conferences and schools in my field but denied a visa because of an absurd system, that is, quite frankly, discriminatory.

@Relaxed I'm usually good at not taking opinions personally, however your previous remark did touch a nerve, which made me go off. I appreciate your understanding and your acknowledgement of this prevailing issue. I did end up cancelling my appointment for Lithuania after the responses here.

@dda Oh I had no idea what that word meant! I feel very enlightened now, thanks to you!

@NotEuler I meant you could book an appointment if you think you may be going to a particular country for summer school, then cancel it if your plans change. Booking an appointment doesn’t require actual submission of an application at the same time AFAIK

@Traveller How can I think I may be going to a particular country even before there is an announcement for the summer school? It's not like I am picking the summer school based on the country; it's the other way round. Also, for a German visa one needs to fill the Videx form (with specific travel plans) before booking an appointment.
